# Consulta con tabla pivot - SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, sql

Tengo 3 tablas:

```
Persona(IdPersona(PK), NombreYApellido, IdTelefono);  
Telefono(IdTelefono(PK), Numero, IdTipoTelefono);   
TipoTelefono(IdTipoTelefono(PK), Descripcion);
```

Para relacionarlas creé la tabla

```
PersonasTipoTelefono(IdPersonaTipoTelefono(PK), IdPersona, IdTelefono, IdTipoTelefono)
```

Necsito traer todos los teléfonos que corresponden a cada persona e hice la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT  P.[Nombre y Apellido], T.NumeroTelefono, TT.Descripcion, PTT.*
   FROM    PersonaTipoTelefono PTT INNER JOIN
           Personas P ON PTT.IdPersona = P.IdPersona INNER JOIN
           Telefono T ON PTT.IdTelefono = T.IdTelefono AND 
           P.IdTelefono = T.IdTelefono INNER JOIN
           TipoTelefono TT ON PTT.IdTipoTelefono = TT.IdTipoTelefono AND 
            T.IdTipoTelefono = TT.IdTipoTelefono
```

El problema es que me devuelve solo un número de teléfono por cada persona cuando hay personas que tienen asignados 2 o 3 números de teléfono.

Comment: No veo cómo puede ser posible lo que dices, con las tablas que posteaste. La tabla `Persona` tiene como llave el `IdPersona`, hasta acá todo bien, pero además tiene un `IdTelefono`. Si tiene un `IdTelefono` y en la tabla sólo puede haber una fila por `IdPersona`, cómo es posible que una persona tenga asignado más de un teléfono??. El diseño, como está escrito, no hace mucho sentido

Comment: Ok gracias, no me había percatado de ese error, voy a empezar corrigiendo eso.

Comment: sumando a lo de lamak, que sentido tiene tener IdTipoTelefono en la tabla telefono?? creo que hiciste un modelo, te diste cuenta que no andaba, lo modificaste para que anduviera, pero te quedaron mal las tablas originales..

Comment: Si vas a hacer cambios al diseño, te recomiendo lo siguiente: Primero, crea una columna para los nombres y otras para los apellidos, nunca sabrás cuándo necesitarás esta información por separado. Quitar la columna IdTelefono de esa tabla. La tabla `Telefono` quizás la puedes renombrar como `TelefonoPersona`, donde puedes tener una llave primaria `IdTelefono` y la columna `IdPersona` que sea una llave foránea a la tabla `Persona`

Comment: tu modelo es correcto, tu error esta en tu segundo join en el cual aun no cruzas con tipo de teléfono y en el on ya lo estas ligando, te recomiendo escribir tus consultas hacia abajo, para que puedas ver bien lo que estas programando, te voy a escribir en respuestas como quedaria la consulta!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pablo, en primer lugar el titulo PIVOT se presta a confusión por la clausula PIVOT, lo mejor sería hablar de una tabla "ternaria" o de relación "ternaria". En segundo lugar, creo que la relación ternaria debiera ser:

```
PersonasTelefono(IdPersonaTelefono(PK), IdPersona, IdTelefono)
```

El tipo de teléfono es un atributo del teléfono y no de la persona, piénsalo así: "una persona puede tener varios teléfonos y cada uno de estos es de un tipo", la parte "una persona puede tener varios teléfonos" lo resuelves mediante la entidad `PersonasTelefono`, y lo de "cada uno de estos es de un tipo" ya lo tienes resuelto en la propia entidad/tabla `Telefono` y `TipoTelefono`. Finalmente tu consulta sería algo así:

```
SELECT     P.NombreYApellido, 
           T.NumeroTelefono, 
           TT.Descripcion,
           FROM   Persona P
           INNER JOIN PersonasTelefono PT
                 ON PT.IdPersona = P.IdPersona
           INNER JOIN Telefono T
                 ON T.IdTelefono= P.IdTelefono
           INNER JOIN TipoTelefono TT 
               ON TT.IdTipoTelefono= T.IdTipoTelefono
```

Te comento, que tal como está escrita la consulta solo listaría personas que tienen algún teléfono, dependiendo de la necesidad esto podría ser un problema, de todas formas lo solucionarías haciendo uso de los `LEFT JOIN`. No olvides además incorporar índices en `PersonasTelefono` para `IdPersona` y `IdTelefono` eso permitirá que el motor optimice mejor la consulta.

Answer (score 0):

Tu modelo es correcto, te agrego los FK(Foreign Key), para que te des una idea mas amplia:
Persona(IdPersona(PK), NombreYApellido, IdTelefono(FK));
Telefono(IdTelefono(PK), Numero, IdTipoTelefono(FK));
TipoTelefono(IdTipoTelefono(PK), Descripcion);

```
   --- primero tienes que iniciar con tu tabla principal que en este caso es personas
   select *
   from personas P
   --- tienes que hacer el join con tu primera referencia que es telefono
   inner join telefono t
   on p.IdTelefono = t.IdTelefono
   --- tu tercer nivel es el tipo de telefono que viene de telefono
   inner join PersonaTipoTelefono ptt
   on t.IdTipoTelefono = ptt.IdTipoTelefono;
```